# How to use warp tool to create this circular distort effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

So I just randomly saw this image on behance and I was just curious how it was created. To me it seems like the creator used warp tool but I am just stuck on how he or she was able to warp the text in a radial direction with amazing consistency in the flow...

[image]

Comment: There's no need to say thank you on the question, you can thank answers by upvoting the good ones and accepting the one that solves your problem the best. Check [ask] and take the [tour] to learn more.

Comment: I'm not certain *any* warp tool was used here. A "warp tool" or "twist" feature would not leave the verticals as vertical. They would skew as well. I think it was carefully plotted out editing, not quick and easy tool use. If anything it's far more like liquify along a path.

Comment: Since the effect is not perfectly consistent (note the lack of warps in certain spots where an automated effect would have put them) I suspect this was an artistic choice by the creator, done manually with oval guides to keep the warp direction consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been created using the Warp tool, and some oval guides, as a starting point.

However it would appear to have been done manually only on specific parts of the design, and perhaps tweaked later, by adding/removing nodes, fixing inconsistent curves, etc.  I certainly don't think it's just some automated one-click effect.

I created a similar example just to see if it was possible using the techniques described above.  Obviously, I did this rather quickly for the sake of creating an example, but I suspect much more care was taken by the person who created the original.

[image]